# Optimize self join

Tags: sql, oracle, view, subquery, self-join

I am using below query. Since the data I am trying to self join is pretty huge it is taking a lot of time. Can somebody please guide me as to how to optimize this query?

I am also looking into adding indices. I have 19 columns in total.  I have around 1000,000 rows in each table for a month. Could somebody please suggest the best method to approach this problem?

**Explain plan :**

```
OPERATION    OBJECT_NAME     CARDINALITY     COST 

 SELECT STATEMENT 
     5222342     34282 

 SORT 
     1     

 PX COORDINATOR 


 PX SEND 
 :TQ10000    1     

 SORT 
     1     

 PX BLOCK 
     18      466 

 TABLE ACCESS 
 SUCCESS_SIXMONTHS_JUL   18      466 

 Filter Predicates 

 AND 

 COLUMN14=:B1 

 COLUMN7=:B2 

 COLUMN13>=:B3 

 SORT 
     1     

 PX COORDINATOR 


 PX SEND 
 :TQ20000    1     

 SORT 
     1     

 PX BLOCK 
     18      466 

 TABLE ACCESS 
 SUCCESS_SIXMONTHS_JUL   18      466 

 Filter Predicates 

 AND 

 COLUMN14=:B1 

 COLUMN7=:B2 

 COLUMN13>=:B3 

 PX COORDINATOR 


 PX SEND 
 :TQ30001    5222342     34282 

 HASH 
     5222342     34282 

 PX RECEIVE 
     5222342     34282 

 PX SEND 
 :TQ30000    5222342     34282 

 HASH 
     5222342     34282 

 PX BLOCK 
     5222342     490 

 TABLE ACCESS 
 START_SIXMONTHS_JUL     5222342     490
```

**SQL :**

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  StMT.id1
  , TIMESTAMP_for_start_message
  , (SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP_for_success_message)
     FROM SuccessMessageTable
     WHERE
       (id1 = StMT.id1)
       AND (someDate = StMT.someDate)
       AND (jobID = StMT.jobID)
       AND (TIMESTAMP_for_success_message >= StMT.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message)) TIMESTAMP_for_success_message
, (SELECT MIN(seconds_for_success_message)
     FROM SuccessMessageTable
     WHERE
       (id1 = StMT.id1)
       AND (someDate = StMT.someDate)
       AND (jobID = StMT.jobID)
       AND (TIMESTAMP_for_success_message >= StMT.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message)) seconds_for_success_message
  , StMT.someDate
  , StMT.jobID
FROM StartMessageTable StMT
ORDER BY id1, jobID, TIMESTAMP_for_start_message;
```

Comment: @madhivanan: Thank you for editing the code for me. I am looking o improve this self join and need to get this done by tonight. I have around 1000,000 rows in each table for a month. Could somebody please suggest the best method to approach this problem

Comment: Its will be easy to understand, if you post the explain plan for the above query.

Comment: Get rid of subqueries in favour of joins. Put indices on column present in WHERE clause.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti: could you please post a sample query with indices please!!!

Comment: @GauravSoni: Posting explain plan in the question

Comment: For repeating sub-queries, use `subquery factoring`. i.e. `WITH` clause.

Comment: Format the explain plan properly. Poorly formatted explain plan is useless. Read http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/oracle-explain-plan/ for help. Set the `linesize` accordingly to get the proper formatted `plan table` result.

Answer (score 1):

For performance tuning related questions, you should always come up with the `execution plan` at least.

As a start, you can rewrite the query using `subquery factoring`. If you are using a sub-query multiple times, it would be better to use it as `WITH` clause. You don't have to redefine the same subquery multiple times. Instead we just use the query name defined in the WITH clause, making the query much easier to read.

For example,

```
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT MIN(SMT.TIMESTAMP_for_success_message)
     FROM SuccessMessageTable SMT, StartMessageTable StMT
     WHERE
       (SMT.id1 = StMT.id1)
       AND (SMT.someDate = StMT.someDate)
       AND (SMT.jobID = StMT.jobID)
       AND (SMT.TIMESTAMP_for_success_message >= StMT.TIMESTAMP_for_start_message)
)
SELECT ... FROM DATA A, table1 b, table2 c
...
```

As an example, I have modified your sub-query to fetch data from `SuccessMessageTable` and `StartMessageTable` tables. This `temporary` result set can be used to `join` with other tables to fetch the desired rows.

By doing this, the sub-query result set will be fetched once and resolved as a `temporary table`. Hence, **repeated references to the subquery may be more efficient as the data is easily retrieved from the temporary table, rather than being repeatedly queried by each reference**.

Read more about it http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php

**EDIT**

I think the following query should be working fine for you -

```
SELECT   stmt.id, 
         stmt.somedate, 
         stmt.jobid, 
         stmt.timestamp_for_start_message, 
         min(smt.timestamp_for_success_message) timestamp_for_success_message,
         min(smt.seconds_for_success_message)   seconds_for_success_message ,
FROM     successmessagetable smt, 
         startmessagetable stmt 
WHERE    ( 
                  smt.id1 = stmt.id1) 
AND      ( 
                  smt.somedate = stmt.somedate) 
AND      ( 
                  smt.jobid = stmt.jobid) 
AND      ( 
                  smt.timestamp_for_success_message >= stmt.timestamp_for_start_message) 
GROUP BY stmt.id, 
         stmt.somedate, 
         stmt.jobid, 
         stmt.timestamp_for_start_message 
ORDER BY stmt.id1, 
         stmt.jobid, 
         smt.timestamp_for_start_message;
```

Comment: While the WITH clause is probably a good idea, you seem to have references to two tables in it, but you only list one.

Comment: It was just an example sort. Still, let me rectify it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Thank you for posting the corrected query. I am trying to run this currently. What I am stuck at is what do I need to add in the select statement at the bottom. Do I need to create a temp table at all? Sorry this sounds very naive questions but I have a time crunch and any guidance would be helpful

Comment: You don't have to create any temp table. You need to put the repeating sub-query into the `WITH` clause as I have shown above. that WITH clause acts as a temp table for you. it is named as `DATA` table in the example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The current join query would take a lot more time altogether. Can say this as have already tried doing the same.

Comment: @DataAnalyst: are you referring to the query I wrote?  If so, your comment should be attached to my answer.  What are the keys on the two tables?  What are the indexes on the two tables?   You should really include at least an outline schema of the two tables — with the columns mentioned in the two queries, plus a dummy column or ellipsis (three dots, …) to indicate where there are more columns.  Only indexes on the columns mentioned in the query are relevant.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Thanks . Looks like the query is working fine. But i need the  MIN(SMT.TIMESTAMP_for_success_message) column displayed. How do i do that?

Comment: @DataAnalyst, look at the edit. I have posted a query. Looks like you won't need the WITH clause. Just use the new  query. Should give you the desired result.

Comment: Note that the original query also selects SomeDate and JobID, and they'll be needed in the GROUP BY too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes the aggregate would need the `GROUP BY` for the other columns in select list.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: I need to have all the occurrence of start message and only min of success message and hence I am not sure if the latest query with group by would work. Is there a way to display the min(columnname) using WITH clause query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is equivalent to what you asked for.  I'm not convinced that the DISTINCT is still necessary.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       M.ID1,
       M.Timestamp_for_start_message,
       MIN(S.Timestamp_for_success_message) Timestamp_for_success_message,
       MIN(S.Seconds_for_success_message) Seconds_for_success_message
       M.SomeDate,
       M.JobID
  FROM StartMessageTable M
  JOIN SuccessMessageTable S
    ON S.ID1 = M.ID1
   AND S.SomeDate = M.SomeDate
   AND S.JobID = M.JobID
   AND S.Timestamp_for_success_message >= M.Timestamp_for_start_message
 GROUP BY M.ID1, M.Timestamp_for_start_message, M.SomeDate, M.JobID
 ORDER BY M.ID1, M.JobID, M.Timestamp_for_start_message;
```

Note that it is not clear that the 'Seconds_for_success_message' value will come from the same row as the 'Timestamp_for_success_message' value.  It probably will, but the structure of the query does not guarantee it — but that was true of the query in the question too.

Comment: What is the purpose of having the same column twice `MIN(S.Timestamp_for_success_message)`?

Comment: @LalitKumarB: I said I can see no purpose, but the original query in the question seems to have the same sub-select twice in the list, yielding the same result with two names, so I've written the query the same way.  And now I've spotted the difference...

Comment: I understand. I think the sub-query is unnecessarily written twice. Not actually being joined, I wonder how it is useful to OP.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: sorry for the typo. I have edited the sample query. I am trying to get 2 separate columns from the same successmessage table and getting its min.

Comment: @DataAnalyst: Phew; I didn't notice that you'd changed that column name when you added the query plan — I was beginning to doubt my eyes or sanity!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sorry my bad. It took me a little while to update it ..also the page had to be refreshed then..I appreciate your query help here!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, I was referring to your query for the join. I could not tag you in here and hence commented on the above solution. I do not have index on the query yet.